# SAGA - Raster statistics for polygons is not working

Tags: raster, saga

I would like to generate the raster statistics for one polygon with the raster tool "Raster statistics for polygons".
The first try:
My data is this GeoTIFF and a Polygon both in EPSG:25832. I dont have any non-ascii characters in the path.
The second try:
I convert the GeoTIFF into SAGA Grid and try it again, but it wont work to.

Here is my Errormessage from the second try:

```
QGIS version: 3.20.0-Odense
QGIS code revision: decaadbb31
Qt version: 5.12.8
Python version: 3.8.5
GDAL version: 3.0.4
GEOS version: 3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020
PDAL version: 2.0.1 (git-version: Release)
SAGA version 7.3.0 is not officially supported - algorithms may encounter issues
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Raster statistics for polygons' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'COUNT' : True, 'GRIDS' : ['/home/kai/Downloads/rastsdat.sdat'], 'MAX' : True, 'MEAN' : True, 'METHOD' : 0, 'MIN' : True, 'NAMING' : 1, 'POLYGONS' : '/home/kai/Downloads/test.shp', 'QUANTILE' : 0, 'RANGE' : True, 'RESULT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'STDDEV' : True, 'SUM' : True, 'VAR' : True }

shapes_grid "Grid Statistics for Polygons" -GRIDS "/home/kai/Downloads/rastsdat.sgrd" -POLYGONS "/home/kai/Downloads/test.shp" -METHOD 0 -NAMING 1 -COUNT true -MIN true -MAX true -RANGE true -SUM true -MEAN true -VAR true -STDDEV true -QUANTILE 0 -RESULT "/tmp/processing_PkHpQb/0e5c595da6be48938baab97ac9ab141c/RESULT.shp"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 7.3.0

Unknown option 'QUANTILE'
____________________________
library path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/saga/
library name: libshapes_grid
library : shapes_grid
tool : Grid Statistics for Polygons
identifier : 2
author : O.Conrad (c) 2003, Quantile Calculation (c) 2007 by Johan Van de Wauw
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________


Usage: saga_cmd shapes_grid 2 [-GRIDS <str>] [-POLYGONS <str>] [-NAMING <str>] [-METHOD <str>] [-PARALLELIZED <str>] [-RESULT <str>] [-COUNT <str>] [-MIN <str>] [-MAX <str>] [-RANGE <str>] [-SUM <str>] [-MEAN <str>] [-VAR <str>] [-STDDEV <str>] [-GINI <str>] [-QUANTILES <str>]
-GRIDS:<str> Grids
Grid list (input)
-POLYGONS:<str> Polygons
Shapes (input)
-NAMING:<str> Field Naming
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] grid number
[1] grid name
Default: 1
-METHOD:<str> Method
Choice
Available Choices:
[0] simple and fast
[1] polygon wise (cell centers)
[2] polygon wise (cell area)
[3] polygon wise (cell area weighted)
Default: 0
-PARALLELIZED:<str> Use Multiple Cores
Boolean
Default: 0
-RESULT:<str> Statistics
Shapes (optional output)
-COUNT:<str> Number of Cells
Boolean
Default: 1
-MIN:<str> Minimum
Boolean
Default: 1
-MAX:<str> Maximum
Boolean
Default: 1
-RANGE:<str> Range
Boolean
Default: 1
-SUM:<str> Sum
Boolean
Default: 1
-MEAN:<str> Mean
Boolean
Default: 1
-VAR:<str> Variance
Boolean
Default: 1
-STDDEV:<str> Standard Deviation
Boolean
Default: 1
-GINI:<str> Gini
Boolean
Default: 0
-QUANTILES:<str> Percentiles
Text
Execution completed in 0.94 seconds
Results:
{'RESULT': '/tmp/processing_PkHpQb/0e5c595da6be48938baab97ac9ab141c/RESULT.shp'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /tmp/processing_PkHpQb/0e5c595da6be48938baab97ac9ab141c/RESULT.shp
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Is there any known bug or something about this SAGA tool ?

Comment: The name of the option seems to be QUANTILES but the error message complains about unknown option QUANTILE. I wonder if the command gets truncated for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

ohh, yes, you are right. I didnt see the wood for trees.
Is it possible to execute a saga tool via "termial" in qgis and change the option "quantile" to "quantiles" ?

Best regards
Kai